# MongoDB GridFS authentication not working

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, gridfs

I am trying to insert data to a MongoDB 3.4 GridFS storage with enabled authentication via a Spring Boot app, but I keep getting this error:

> Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized on user to execute command { find: \"fs.files\", filter: { metadata.fieldname: \"someContent\" } }' on server ip:27017"

I created a user with "superuser" rights for this:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
{
   user: "admin", 
   pwd: "password", 
   roles:["root"]
})
```

My spring boot application.properties are:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=ip
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.username=admin
spring.data.mongodb.password=password
spring.data.mongodb.database=user
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
```

I already tried the "old" MongoDB roles with no luck:

```
db.createUser(
{
   user: "admin",
   pwd: "password",
   roles: [
             { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
             { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
             { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
             { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" }
          ]
})
```

Reading and writing to other (non-gridFS) databases works perfectly.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: This seems to be a spring boot configuration problem... When using "Robo 3T" I can read from fs.files and fs.chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
I still had an AbstractMongoConfiguration class lying around.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
  //some code...
}
```

Deleting it solved it.
You have to either use application.properties OR a java class for MongoDB configuration.